# I am creating a running time calculator and am having trouble using functions

Tags: python

Here is my current code:

```
  def get_input():
        pace = str(input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: "))
        distance = float(input("Enter distance [miles]: "))
        mm, ss = int(pace.split(":")[0]), int(pace.split(":")[1])
        return(pace, distance, mm, ss)
    def calculate_time(pace, distance, mm, ss):
        print(pace)
        print(mm)
        print(ss)
        new_sec = mm * 60 
        full_sec = ss + new_sec
        print(full_sec)
        print(distance)
        total_time_sec = full_sec * distance
        print(total_time_sec)
        seconds_per_mile = total_time_sec / 60
        hours = int(seconds_per_mile // 60)
        print(seconds_per_mile)
        print(hours)
        minutes = int((total_time_sec - (hours * 3600))//60)
        print(minutes)
        seconds = int(total_time_sec - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)))
        print(seconds)
        print(pace, full_sec, distance)
        return(seconds, minutes, hours)
    def display_time(pace, distance, mm, ss, seconds, minutes, hours):
        if seconds < 10:
            print(hours,":",minutes,":0",seconds, sep="")
        else:
            print(hours,":",minutes,":",seconds, sep="")
        return()
    def main():
        pace, distance, mm, ss = get_input()
        new_sec, full_sec, total_time_sec, seconds_per_mile, hours, minutes, seconds = calculate_time(pace, distance, mm, ss)
        display_time(pace, distance, mm, ss, seconds, minutes, hours)
    main()
```

I'm not terribly good at using functions. I don't believe I have a full understanding of returning stuff any whatnot, either.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/homework 3 test.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python33/homework 3 test.py", line 34, in main
    new_sec, full_sec, total_time_sec, seconds_per_mile, hours, minutes, seconds = calculate_time(pace, distance, mm, ss)
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

The point of the function is to get the user to input their pace and distance and output the time needed to run the distance.

For example:

```
Enter pace [mm:ss]: 8:15
Enter distance [miles]: 26.2
3:36:09
```

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. I don't necessarily want to know how to do it to the tee, but I am having a lot of trouble and need a bit of a boost.

Comment: You should also state what your problem is, exactly - does your problem run at all (I doubt it does), if not, what is the exact error message including the full traceback? If it does run, how exactly does it behave differently from your expectations?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/homework 3 test.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python33/homework 3 test.py", line 34, in main
    new_sec, full_sec, total_time_sec, seconds_per_mile, hours, minutes, seconds = calculate_time(pace, distance, mm, ss)
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Comment: That's the error I get with the above code.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) When you're learning how to use a new language feature it's a Good Idea to write a tiny little program that uses that feature and experiment until you're comfortable with it. And then if you get stuck you have a nice compact piece of code you can post here to get help with, rather than lumbering us with a wall of text. 2) You should learn how to use `print()` properly so you don't need to have multiple lines of `print()` calls. 3) Your code would be easier to read if you put a blank line or two between functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit hard to read (check out [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), but one obvious problem with your function `calculate_time()` is that it does

```
return(seconds, minutes, hours)   # return a three-element tuple
```

but that `main()` tries to unpack that into six variables:

```
new_sec, full_sec, total_time_sec, seconds_per_mile, hours, minutes, seconds = calculate_time(pace, distance, mm, ss)
```

Some comments:

```
pace = str(input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: "))
mm, ss = int(pace.split(":")[0]), int(pace.split(":")[1])
```

is overly complex. `input()` already returns strings, and there's a nifty Python feature called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that you could use here:

```
pace = input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: ")
mm, ss = [int(item) for item in pace.split(":")]
```

Comment: What do you recommend I do? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Make sure that `calculate_time()` returns exactly the six variables that the calling function expects to get, in exactly that order.

Comment: @JCJG: "It's not working" is not a problem description. How exactly is it not working? Your computer expects you to define your problem unambiguously, so do we :)